# spark rdd for small files from hadoop

Tags: apache-spark

i have lots of tiny small xml files with 1 records each.I am using spark for some transformation and load into DB.when i am using files from local with `sc.wholeTextFiles(args[0]).values();` its working fine and  as i can see the logs 
like ...

```
1 record transformed..
1 record transformed..
```

and at for each partition am loading into db and getting logs like

```
2000 records loaded 
0 rejected.
```

But when loading files from hadoop with `sc.wholeTextFiles(args[0]).values();` its showing file doesnt exists.

so i tried with `sc.TextFile(args[0]);`..this is working but taking a lots of time and from log i can see its processing each file with transformation and loading into db .logs like

```
1 record transformed..
1 records loaded..
0 rejected..
```

again

```
1 record transformed..
1 records loaded..
```

Am unable to understand what is going on inside spark.How to solve this.

Comment: What are you using for `args(0)`, that is the path? It should be the directory of the files.

Comment: yes it is the directory only

Comment: using rdd.coalesce(int) somhow working..but after some time datanode is crashing...i think because of lots of open connection..

Comment: What's the full path your passing as the directory to `wholeTextFiles`?

Comment: its like "hdfs://localhost:8020/home/hadoop/data"

Comment: You should use the public IP address or server name for the Name Node, not localhost. That will break if the driver isn't running on the same machine. I don't think it affects the slave tasks, too, but I could be wrong. `hadoop fs -ls "hdfs://localhost:8020/home/hadoop/data` will only work on the Name Node machine, for example.